# Combining Google Login Api with my Application login

Tags: node.js, react-native, react-google-login

I am building a react native application with a node js backend and JWT authentication, when a user creates an account their details in store in MySQL database and when a user logs in an access token is generated with JWT, and is used to make API requests in react native app. everything is working fine. now I want to integrate Google login, how do I make users that log in with Google to be able to make API requests like the users I have on the database